# Custom suggestions/completion in PHP function from JSON file in PhpStorm

Tags: php, json, autocomplete, phpstorm, autosuggest

I have a `translate("")` function and I want PhpStorm to start suggesting values from a JSON file when I start typing between the quotes.

The idea is that I have a JSON file with translation strings and when I start typing it should suggest translations which are already included in that json file, based on the characters I already typed of course.

After some research, I do not think this is currently possible in PhpStorm, but maybe someone here has an idea or an alternative.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have time and desire to convert your JSON file to another JSON file (using a special format) then have a look at PHP Toolbox plugin, it can offer such stuff. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8133-php-toolbox P.S.That `translate()` function -- is part of some framework/CMS? Maybe a plugin for that framework already supports it (like Symfony/LaravelIdea can do AFAIK). E.g. something like "Text Domain Completion for WordPress" plugin does...

Comment: You can also use Advanced Metadata functionality (to provide a list of acceptable values for specific function) .. but I'm not sure at all if it will work well here (translation context, big list of possible values). Anyway: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html

Comment: I made it work by writing a script that adds my translation strings into the PhpStorm meta file. Not ideal, but it does the job. Thank you!

Comment: Please post it as an answer -- it will help others in a similar situation (question with accepted answer has better visibility in search results). Just describe what you have used etc (if you can show a screenshot of how the completion looks in the IDE -- that  will be a big bonus). If the file with translation strings is in some standard format (existing CMS/framework) then please also consider sharing your basic conversion script (as a gist is perfectly fine -- just to show the overall process/idea).

Comment: Will do on monday! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work using PhpStorm advanced metadata.

I created a `.phpstorm.meta.php` file in the project root, this will add auto completion/suggestions for the first (`0`) argument of the `translate` method:

```
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {
    expectedArguments(
        \App\Helper\TranslationHelper::translate(),
        0,
        /* Generated */
        "Auto completion result",
        "This is also a suggested result",
        "Give me more suggestions PhpStorm",
        /* Generated */
    );
}
```

And then wrote a Symfony command that takes strings from my translation file and includes them between the two `/* Generated */` comments:

```
$translations = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->parameterBag->get('app.project.path') . '/resources/translations/de.json'), true);

$metadataPath = $this->parameterBag->get('app.project.path') . '/.phpstorm.meta.php';
$identifier = "/* Generated */";
$regexIdentifier = $this->escape($identifier);
$regex = "/$regexIdentifier(.*?)$regexIdentifier/s";

// Build the arguments string that will be written into the metadata file
$translationsAsArguments = "$identifier\n";
foreach ($translations as $translation) {
    $translationsAsArguments .= "\t\t\"$translation\",\n";
}
$translationsAsArguments .= "\t\t$identifier";

// Write to disk
$translationsMetadata = preg_replace($regex, $translationsAsArguments, file_get_contents($metadataPath));
file_put_contents($metadataPath, $translationsMetadata);
```

*This solution was written with PHP using Symfony 6.3*

The suggestions will look like this in the IDE:
[image: Completion in PhpStorm]